# ChromeDriver instance not getting deleted when Jenkins is Aborted

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am currently running my selenium tests in an AWS EC2 Windows instance (no Selenium Grid)

Step 1 : I trigger the job in Jenkins
Step 2 : ChromeDriver in the slave machine is invoked and my tests are running
Step 3 : I see some tests are failing because of some exception from the console output of Jenkins Build and ABORT the build
Step 4 : I fix the issue and running the Jenkins Job again.

Expected : Jenkins job should start running the tests
Actual : I get an exception saying

*java.io.IOException:Unable to delete "". Tried 3 times waiting 0.1 sec between attempts - Access Denied*

Workaround I follow - I will restart my slave machine and delete the workspace manually after the AWS Slave Service restarts.

What I need - I need to delete the folders from the workspace either before I build the next job and start freshly

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Nailed it by using - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Comment: Referred - https://superuser.com/questions/335138/how-to-close-all-file-handles-under-a-given-folder-programatically