# Jenkins is not stopping the Selenium test execution when aborting jenkins build

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have my jenkins build configured at my slave machine to execute my selenium tests. When I abort the jenkins build during execution, jenkins is not stopping the execution. ChromeDriver is still running for further tests.

Is there any way to stop jenkins execution while build is running?

I have seen some pages related to this question.
[Selenium driver instance persists if test is aborted on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286331/selenium-driver-instance-persists-if-test-is-aborted-on-jenkins)
[ChromeDriver instance not getting deleted when Jenkins is Aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329263/chromedriver-instance-not-getting-deleted-when-jenkins-is-aborted)
https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-60161?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

May be you have stuck chrome driver instances. You can kill them with additional command.

Comment: I am killing them using taskmanager for now, but still one more ChromeDriver.exe is starting up. I guess Jenkins still executes pending test cases even after I abort build.